Instantiating prefabs in Unity
Say I have this script:
public class Cat : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] int id;
    [SerializeField] String name;
    [SerializeField] int age;
}

I have created several prefab objects in Unity. Each one has a Sprite Renderer, Rigidbody 2D, and a Collider. They each have a Cat script component, where I've entered the id, name, and age data for each.
Now, in the game script, I need to instantiate these prefabs based on the id property. I've tried various forms of Resources.Load and Instantiate but I keep getting null. How can I load these objects by ID and add them into the scene?

Can you include the null error. Is it null on the prefab reference? on the Cat script? or on the id? Also can you share the code where you try to instantiate the prefab?

The id property is an int, and both Resources.Load and Instantiate do not accept int, it's not clear how you tried to load, so please provide your various forms.

Generally you shouldn't use Resources most of times.
Easiest in my eyes would be to store all those prefabs in a central ScriptableObject asset and then do e.g.
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class CatDatabase : ScriptableObject 
{
    [SerializeField] private Cat[] cats;

    private Dictionary<int, Cat> catById;

    // Called when the asset is loaded
    private void OnEnable()
    {
       Init();
    }

    public bool TryGetPrefab(int id, out Cat cat)
    {
        // Should never happen but just in case a lazy init fallback 
        if(catById == null) Init();

        return catById.TryGetValue(id, out cat);
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        forach(var cat in cats)
        {
            catById.Add(cat.Id, cat);
        }
    }
}

Actually the Id could even be replaced by simply the index within the array ..

This is great. But I still can't get the object into the scene. I set the position and then do
Instantiate(cat);
but nothing appears on the screen.

@soleil check the hierarchy .. if this is a UI element it requires to be child of a canvas .. if the prefab has a position offset it might also just be spawned out of camera .. the same if your camera has an offset and the object is spawned on 0,0,0 .. many factors possible here

From what I understand, you think that this id is something that any embedded system automatically knows about.
If yes, it is wrong. This is simply a value of the int variable, nothing more.
If you need something like "loading the needed prefab based on a given id, that is set in the serialized field" - you need to implement this mapping yourself.
There are plenty of possible options, some most straightforward ones:

create some loader script, attach it to the gameobject on the scene and add all possible prefabs to a serialized list.
place all of these prefabs into the Resources folder and use Resources.LoadAll method to get all possible prefabs instead of adding them directly to the serialized list.

There are many other options depending on your needs. As I already mentioned above, you have to handle this mapping yourself in any of them.

I understand that id is not something the system automatically knows about. But I assumed this scenario was common enough that there was an established practice for doing so.
